# Sunspot results does not respond_to? total_pages but total_pages can be called as method.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

Trying to understand why the following is so:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :012 > User.solr_search.results.respond_to?(:total_pages)
  => false 
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :013 > User.solr_search.results.total_pages
  => 624
```

While using sunspot 1.3.0 with a the following delegation to the sunspot search object (I do not think the delegation should matter in this case but wanted to include here just in case.):

```
::Sunspot::Search::StandardSearch.class_eval do
  include Enumerable
  delegate(
    :current_page,
    :per_page,
    :total_entries,
    :total_pages,
    :offset,
    :previous_page,
    :next_page,
    :out_of_bounds?,
    :each,
    :in_groups_of,
    :blank?,
    :[],
    :to => :results
  )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone didn't read @Marc-André Lafortune about [method_missing - politely](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2010/11/methodmissing-politely.html).

Comment: Yeah, the problem seems to be in the sunspot gem. That article only applies to ruby 1.9. Thx!